# Is it possible to affect the behavior of all vim commands in normal mode?

Tags: vim

Is there a way to affect the behavior of all vim normal-mode commands?  Say, after every command succeeds, I want to trigger some post-behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot do this; you only have the events at `:help autocmd-events` at your disposal. You would have to overload every normal mode command with a custom mapping; this is especially tricky for commands like `y{motion}`.

Please give more background; what is your final goal? When a question is only about a small technical step, it's difficult to provide a good answer. If you don't tell us **why** you want this, it's easy to succumb to the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Thanks for the answer and pointing out the pitfalls of asking a question.